# Finding Sample Size (n) using the binomial equation for non-parametric test design

Tags: statistics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution, sampling, nonparametric-statistics

Im using the non-parametric binomial equation, found in the link here
https://reliawiki.org/index.php/Reliability_Test_Design

It is written below:

1−C=∑(i=0 to f)(n,i) ((1−R)^i)*R^(n−i)

Where
C is the confidence level,
f is the amount failures
R is the reliability
n is the amount of samples

I am trying to solve for n, when the amount of failures = 1

I have solved for n, when failures = 0, but when failures is 1 the equation takes a shape im not familiar with.

Is anyone familiar with solving this equation?

Thanks,

Comment: Please format your math using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is your equation you're trying to solve?

Comment: If your equation when $f=0$ is $1-C=R^n$ then you get $n=\frac{\log(1-C)}{\log(R)}$
But if your equation when $f=1$ is $1-C=R^n+n(1-R)R^{n-1}$ then there is no easy solution unlike you are willing to do something complicated with the Lambert W function